# Generic types, testing in java

Tags: java, generics, junit

I have a public class `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, an arraylist `private final List<T> items`, and also an access method which looks like this:

```
public T get(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }
```

I wrote a JUnit test for method in the class.

```
 public class HeapTest<T extends Comparable<T>> {
   
      @Test
        public void test1(){
    .
    .
    .
            Integer [] result = new Integer[n];
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                result[i]= (Integer) heap.get(i);
            .
            .
            .
        }
    
    }
```

Why do I need to cast (Integer) heap.get(i) when get() returns generic type T?

Comment: How did you declare `heap` ?

Comment: I edited post and added how i did it

Comment: @Banana, your edit doesn't include the declaration of the variable `heap`.  The most likely cause is that you wrote `Heap` instead of e.g. `Heap<Integer>`.

Comment: Also,  I don't see the point of typing the test class, ie use just `class HeapTest {` instead of `class HeapTest<T extends Comparable<T>> {`